# How to make this settable property in a swift protocol work

Tags: swift

I have this code in a playground:

```
protocol SettableName {
    var name: String {get set}
}

struct SettableNameImpl: SettableName {
    var actualName: String?
    var name: String {
        get {
            if let name = actualName {
                return name
            } else {
                return ""
            }
        }
        set (newName) {
            self.actualName = newName
        }
    }
}

struct Something {
    var settable: SettableName

    func setName(name: String) {
        settable.name = name <-- "cannot assign to result of this expression"
    }
}
```

I'm getting "cannot assign to the result of this expression" in the `setName` method. I cannot for the life of me understand why.

Comment: Is this all code you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing name property of settable in `Something` you are changing the value of `Something` itself and thats why `mutating` keyword must be place before setName function. Hope I was clear enough.

```
struct Something {

    var settable: SettableName

    mutating func setName(name: String) {

        settable.name = name // "error is gone now"
    }
}
```